# Using flock() in c unix, which kind of error I receive trying opening file in another process?

Tags: c, file, unix, client, flock

I'm using flock()  in my code server/client  to allow the reading of file only to one process. But if another process try to open that file the computation go in pause I think, instead I would handle an error to give an output that explain to user what's the matter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other process will not receive an error when it does the `open()` call.  Calls to `flock()` are *advisory* - the lock is not enforced by making calls to `open()`, `read()`, or `write()` fail.  Other processes need to do their own `flock()` calls to determine if the file has been locked for reading or writing.

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) for complete information.

Comment: Thank you =D, I have bypassed the problem using alarm() in order to understand if I'm stuck on flock()

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use mandatory file locking, not advisory file locking. The advisory file locking that `flock` does only prevents two processes from locking the same file at the same time. It has no effect on uncooperative processes that don't try to lock files.

Your UNIX may or may not have mandatory file locks and they may or may not be enabled.

Comment: Also some mandatory lock implementations are faulty. The default mandatory locking provided by Linux and Solaris is setting set-group-id bit and removing group execute bit. `read(2)`, `write(2)` and `open(2)` fails as expected in Solaris and Linux. The files locked with the method above will not prevent `unlink(2)` though, so the files can be removed without error, despite mandatory lock. (Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment 3rd ed pg 496)